# Passing QAbstractItemModel* to C++ class

Tags: c++, qt, qml

Consider:

```
class Utility : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Utility(QObject* parent = nullptr) : QObject(parent) {}

    Q_INVOKABLE void test(const QAbstractItemModel* model)
    {

    }
};
```

Set up in `main` via `qmlRegisterSingletonInstance("pgqt34", 1, 0, "Utility", &utility);`

and QML is:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15

import pgqt34 1.0

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    ListModel {
        id: listModel
    }

    onActiveChanged: {
        Utility.test(listModel);
    }
}
```

I consistently get `Error: Unknown method parameter type: const QAbstractItemModel*` for Qt 5.15.2 compilations, but Qt 6.x+ works OK.  What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

1. Straight way:

   Q_INVOKABLE void test(const QObject* obj)
   {
   auto model = qobject_cast(obj);
   }
2. Declare `QAbstractItemModel*` as a metatype. But, I'm not sure if it's a working solution.

Comment: Wow, SO ruins my code. Please click Edit link and see my original code. What I meant in 1st way: `auto model = qobject_cast<QAbstractItemModel*>(obj);`

Comment: I didn't have much luck with declaring `QAbstractItemModel*` as a metatype.  It was seeming like Qt already does that.  Will try out your suggestion #1 shortly.  Don't love it I gotta admit, but we do what we have to right :)